# Account String Expansion not working correctly

Tags: teradata

Can anyone tell me what are the steps required to enable account string expansion? The account string in dbc.acctg is captured as "$E$      DBAARCHIVE  &D&H0&S" instead of expanding the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that `&H0` is a valid ASE variable. Also the expansion of `&D&H&S` (17 characters) combined with the remainder of your account string will exceed 30 characters with the whitespace included.

Have you tried `$E$DBAARCHIVE&D&H&S`? This should expand to 30 characters exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I understand that the expansion may lead to more than 30 chars, but at least it should expand.

I actually got the reason from Teradata CS:

Do not use ARC with any ASE code Because ARC generates two kinds of requests:
• SQL type requests that go through the Parser and expand the ASE variables.
• Direct requests from ARCMAIN to the AMP that bypass the Parser. As a result, substitution variables are not expanded, so the rows in DBC.AMPUsage contain literal ASE codes rather than the expected date, hour, and timestamp values.

That is the issue, using ARC with ASE code.

Thanks,
Piyush